# Simple memcpy Implementation Segfaults

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I am doing work for and OS class and for some reason bcc needs a memcpy even though I haven't called it in the code and its unavailable, so I'm rolling my own, however it keeps segfaulting
`

```
void memcpy( void* destination, void* source, size_t bytes )
{
        size_t i = 0;
        char* destination__ = ( char* ) destination;
        char* source__ = ( char* ) source;
        if( !( destination__ == source__ ) )
        {
                for( ; i < bytes; ++i )
                        destination__[ i ] = source__[ i ];
        }
}
```

It seems to segfault and I am not sure why, it does fine when things are malloced but not for something like the following.

`

```
char* foo = "Hello";
char* bar = "Goodbye";
memcpy( bar, foo, 5 );
```

I have a feeling this is because foo and bar are likely global data, and it has something to do with that but Im not sure. I wouldent be asking except for the fact that I have found other implementations [that](https://gist.github.com/orangejulius/3843041) are [the](https://jlmedina123.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/memcpy-implementation/) same/[similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217126/memcpy-implementation-strict-aliasing) online [elsewhere.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-memcpy/) It crashes when compiled with regular ol' gcc which Im using to validate outside the OS Im building that has no diagnostics. Im confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: Does it still segfault if you declare your strings as `char[]` rather than `char*`? I think the problem is that those strings have been put in memory that's read only. And I think this is a duplicate, but I haven't yet found the original

Comment: @xing Will standardized implementations of memcpy crash when this happens? Due to Time Randall's insight I will close the question if it does.

Comment: @Tim Randall No it does not crash if I do that.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain It isn't your `memcpy` implementation that's broken, but your test code.

Comment: `char* bar` --> `char bar[SIZE]`

Comment: Behavior of your test driver is undefined. You can't modify string literals.

Comment: Grazie everyone, I just tested the standard memcpy in this case and it segfaults as well. Thank you all for your help.