# Assigning the value from the void pointer to a non void pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have a situation where in the address inside the void pointer to be copied to a another pointer. Doing this without a type cast gives no warnings or errors. The pseudo code looks like

```
structA A;
void * p = &A;
structA * B = p;// Would like to conform this step
```

I don't foresee any problems with this. 
But since this operation is used over a lot of places, I would like to conform whether it can have any replications. Also is there any compiler dependency?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745030/type-punning-with-void-without-breaking-the-strict-aliasing-rule-in-c99

Comment: "Conform whether it has replications"? Why not use simple English: "I would like to check whether it works."

Comment: I had tested this with some pseudo code and it works ok. Still the question was intended to conform there is no possibility of any hidden issues.....Sorry if that had cause a confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is fine and 100% standard.

A `void *` can be converted to and from any other data/object pointer without problems.

Note that data/object restriction: function pointers *do not* convert to/from `void *`.

This is the reason why [you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169), which returns a `void *`.

Answer (score 1):

In C a `void *` is implicitly compatible with any pointer. That why you don't need to cast when e.g. passing pointers of any type to functions taking `void *` arguments, or when assigning to pointer (still of any type) from function returning `void *` (here `malloc` is a good example).